# sfdx project:deploy:start misses files on deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, mdapideploy

It was recommended by sfdx to move from `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi/ -u ...` to `sfdx project:deploy:start -d mdapi/ -o ...`, however, I'm getting errors like:

```
An object 'https_force_com' of type CorsWhitelistOrigin was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

This is due to both the new `sfdx project:convert:source -d mdapi/` and the old deprecated `sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi/` commands convert source CORS without `-meta.xml` in the end of file names.

While with the old deprecated command `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi/ -u ...` I'm able to deploy such files to the destination org, with the new one `sfdx project:deploy:start -d mdapi/ -o ...` it is not possible.

It's worth mentioning, that my original CORS files **DO HAVE** `-meta.xml` in their names.

The question is: **am I missing some flags in convert commands for the new deploy command to execute properly? Or is this a bug and I should log it with salesforce support?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't posted the bug report, but I have resolved the issue by:

- updating the node version from 16 to 18,
- running only `sf project deploy start` from the root directory of the project without converting it to mdapi format.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug. I would recommend [logging a bug on github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli), as that is the official channel for submitting these kinds of issues. In the interim, I suggest simply using [`project retrieve start`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_retrieve_start_unified) from an org with options like `-m CorsWhitelistOrigin`, rather than trying to convert the metadata.

Comment: Thank you, will log it.